# How to use a Reactjs library inside a React Native Webview component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

So as the title say's I am trying to run a Reactjs library inside a React Native Webview but I have not had any luck.

**My Webview**

```
                   <WebView
                        source={{html: html}}
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            marginLeft: 0,
                            marginRight: 0,
                            marginTop: 21,
                            marginBottom: 21,
                            width: '100%',
                            height: 263
                        }}
                        scrollEnabled={false}
                    />
```

**My html string**

```
const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<title>Test React</title>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="root"/>

<script type="text/babel">
    import RadarChart from 'react-svg-radar-chart';
    import 'react-svg-radar-chart/build/css/index.css';

    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
      <p>hello</p>
      <RadarChart
        captions={${captions}}
        data={${data}}
        size={450}
        />
      </div>,
      document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
`;
```

I installed the library in my react native project and tried to concat the component into the html string like this **${RadarChart}** but that didn't work so I am assuming that there is no way to consume a local library with a Webview. Does any one have a better idea?